# Xmonad Confirmation Prompt not appearing

Tags: archlinux, xmonad

I am on Arch Linux trying to configure Xmonad with scripts from [here](https://gitlab.com/dwt1/dotfiles/-/blob/59698df265975c0c6df80adb7e2e2d55ad596ca1/.config/xmonad/xmonad.hs), [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.12/docs/XMonad-Prompt-ConfirmPrompt.html) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xmonad). I have already experience with i3 and leftwm, but xmonad is giving a really hard time.

I have already installed all xmonad packages I could find and gotten most keybindings to work, but the confirmation prompt doesn't show up.

According to the reads, adding this code to xmonad.hs should call the prompt :

```
import XMonad
import XMonad.Prompt.ConfirmPrompt
import XMonad.Actions.SpawnOn

myKeys conf@(XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modm}) = M.fromList $

-- launch a terminal
[ ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_Return), spawn $ XMonad.terminal conf)


-- Quit xmonad
, ((modm , xK_l), confirmPrompt defaultXPConfig "exit" $ io (exitWith ExitSuccess))

   ....
   ....

 -- Swap the focused window with the previous window
, ((modm .|. shiftMask, xK_k     ), windows W.swapUp    )

 ....

]
```

Why is the confirmation prompt not showing?

Comment: What is the "really hard time" you are facing? Haskell has very informative error messages, but you haven't provided any.

Answer (score 0):

That is the line that actually solved it, besides installing xmessage, which is essential on Arch to show x-messages :

, ((modMask .|. shiftMask , xK_y ), confirmPrompt def "exit" $ io exitSuccess)